# What is Public key infrastucture

Tags: wcf, security, wcf-binding, pki

I need to know what is public key infastructure. I need to know is this related to sending requests and response as like WsHttpbinding in WCF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct relation between a PKI and a WCF service. [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) is the infrastructure for creating and managing digital certificates that among many other purposes can be used to encrypt the data flowing through a WCF service.

Once you have a private key and a digital certificate to distribute its coresponding public key you can "forget" about the PKI behind it (in most cases).

If you need further information on how to actually use the certificates to secure your WCF, let me know.

Comment: @Alex I just used my WCF Service client in my local machine. For every request for my client totally 5 requests and responses are sending on. I need to know why and what logic used here in WCF wsHttpBinding

Comment: well... I can't tell you for sure until I do some tests on my own, but I don't know(think) if that's encryption related.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bing.com/search?FORM=IEFM1&q=public+key+infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

AlexDrenea is right on. No direct tie between PKI and WCF.

More info on WCF binding is readily available from:

- [Kurt Claeys](https://web.archive.org/web/20161223065644/http://geekswithblogs.net/claeyskurt/archive/2008/04/22/121508.aspx)

and

- [Mohammed Atef](https://mohammedatef.wordpress.com/tag/wshttpbinding/)

Both are great introductions to the concepts behind binding and the top results on Google.